The proof of existence of an infinite sequence of disjoint sets.
Here is the question I am asking about:
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra.\
a. $\mathcal{M}$ contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets.\
Here are many links I found here for the solution:
1- An infinite $\sigma$-algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets
2- Prove that an infinite sigma algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint sets and is uncountable
But I am wondering why these two solutions considered the complement case, why we need induction?

You have no way to know that $F_n\ne\emptyset$. For instance let
$$
E_1=\{1,2\},\qquad E_2=\{2\}. 
$$
Then $F_2=\emptyset$. You could think that you can somehow order the $E_n$ to avoid this, but it is not clear to me how you would do that, for there could be more complicated combinations. Like
$$
E_1=\{1,2\},\qquad E_2=\{1,3\},\qquad E_3=\{2,3\}. 
$$
Then whichever way you order them, you will get $F_3=\emptyset$.

The usual way to solve this problem is to find a way to guarantee that one still has infinitely many available sets to choose from. For this, one shows

Claim: If $\def\cM{\mathcal M}\cM$ is infinite, then there exists nonempty $E\in\cM$ such that $\{E^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ is infinite.

Having the claim available, you can choose nonempty $E_1$ as in the claim, and now $\cM_1=\{E_1^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra, where by the claim we can get a nonempty $E_2$, disjoint with $E_1$, and such that $\cM_2=\{E_2^c\cap E_1^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ is infinite. Then one keeps inductively obtaining the $E_n$, nonempty and pairwise disjoint.
To prove the claim, suppose that such $E$ does not exist. This means that for any nonempty $E\in\cM$, the set $\{E^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ is finite. So if we fix any nonempty $E\in\cM$, the sets $\{E^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ and $\{E\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}$ are finite. Then
$$
\cM=\{E^c\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}\cup\{E\cap A:\ A\in\cM\}
$$
is finite, a contradiction.

but the question does not have this condition.

What condition?

And how the complement solved this problem? Could you clarify please?

I have added more details.

What about the induction used in the linked questions, why we needed it?

How do you plan to produce infinitely many sets without induction?

ok, I think I got you, thank you very much :)

To clarify, every single time a proof says "and so on", or any other version of it, implying infinitely many steps, one is using induction. It is common not to write it explicitly because it is clear enough for many, but it might be confusing for someone with less experience.

In the paragraph after the claim, did you meant $A \in \mathcal {M}_1$ and $A \in \mathcal {M}_2$ respectively.

No. It wouldn't make sense to use $\mathcal M_1$ to define $\mathcal M_1$.
